# How to solve format exception with flare?

Tags: flutter, flare

I'm using flare but I get this error, error goes away when I use CircularProgressIndicator().

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 7668): PK
```

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

class LoadingIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      // child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      child: FlareActor(
        "assets/loading_1.flr2d",
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        animation: "loading",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

When I've downloaded Flare graphics from [Explore page of 2Dimensions](https://www.2dimensions.com/explore/), I was downloading `.flr2d` files. Which was I guess a project fiel. In flare, you have to export rather than download. I've exported as binary and the output file has `.flr` extension. Thanks @Noob for helping me to find the answer.

Comment: Check your path, if your path is not the issue then check how you had exported your Flare file, 2Dimensions have support over several channels.

Comment: You are welcome @mirkancal. can you please mark my answer as correct, that would be great :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flutter only supports .flr and not .flr2d

I know this because I was running into the same issue.

The animation needs to be created into an flr file otherwise you will always run into this error.

Comment: That's useful. Let me try it.

Comment: looks like all the downloaded files now have .flr2d file extension. How can I download .flr or convert them?

Comment: @mirkancal I am not too sure on where you are getting your flare files, but if you are creating them, you need to export the flare file into .flr  but if you are already using someone elses built flare file then I am not sure you can change a flare file already created. you need to go to the source

Comment: I'm downloading them from explore page of 2dimensions. 
https://www.2dimensions.com/explore/popular/trending/all

Comment: any idea how to open these files in photoshop so that I can save them as png?

Answer (score 11):

As [Noob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56845932/5223309) mentioned your file needs to be a `.flr`

If you are downloading from [2 dimension's page](https://2dimensions.com/explore/popular/trending/all) then you need to go to `Export` at top right from **Flare editor**. Then select file format as `JSON` not `binary`. You should be then downloading the asset as a `.flr` file.

Comment: Thanks but I've already added the solution on the original post. Exporting binary works too by the way.

Comment: Ow alright. I was looking at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794046/how-to-solve-format-exception-with-flare/56966767?noredirect=1#comment100278015_56845932 but thought I should add something extra for others to find easily